# how do I check the internet connection while the application is closed?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web, flutter-test

how do I check the internet connection while the application is closed so that I can synchronize the local data with the server automatically without user intervention like WhatsApp synchronizes messages automatically when the internet is available, please help

Answer (score 1):

You can use the workmanager package. Flutter WorkManager is a wrapper around Android's WorkManager and iOS' performFetchWithCompletionHandler, effectively enabling headless execution of Dart code in the background.
This is especially useful to run periodic tasks, such as fetching remote data on a regular basis. [workmanager package](https://pub.dev/packages/workmanager)